# golang benchmark set testing flags in code

Tags: go, testing, benchmarking, flags

I have a preexisting custom golang benchmark program; It runs benchmraks using [testing.Benchmark](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#Benchmark) on a collection of functions.

This program uses [cobra](https://github.com/spf13/cobra) for input parameters.

How do I use [testing flags](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Testing_flags) in the benchmarks?

I cannot see a way to set them in the code explicitly, and I can't get command line options to work.

Comment: Can you describe your problem in detail with the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

You can call [testing.Init()](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#Init) and then set the test flags you are interested in using [flag.VisitAll()](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#VisitAll).

For example, setting `testing.B.N` to 100:

```
testing.Init()
flag.VisitAll(func(f *flag.Flag) {
    if f.Name == "test.benchtime" {
        f.Value.Set("100x")
}
```